# How to call ng-click before ng-blur?

Tags: html, angularjs

I've created a text input with some suggestions appearing while typing (just like on Google - you are writing something and it suggests you some text).

```
<input id="smartBar" ng-focus="showSuggestions=true" ng-blur="showSuggestions=false" ng-model="smartBar" ng-keydown="smartBarKeyDown($event)" focus-on="smartBar" />
                <table class="suggestionList" ng-show="showSuggestions">
                    <tr ng-repeat="sg in suggestions" ng-class="{highlighedSuggestion: $index == highlightedSuggestion}" ng-click="suggestionClicked($index)">
                        <td ng-repeat="nt in sg.NoteTags" style="padding: 0rem 1rem">
                            {{nt.Tag.Name}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

I want to add possibility to click on one of "suggestions" (there is ng-click attribute in < TR> html attribute). Unfortunately, ng-blur seems to work earlier than ng-click, so when I click on one of options, input loses focus and suggestionList becomes invisible before click is detected.

How can I detect click before hiding suggestionList?

Comment: `setTimeout(hide, 50);`?

Comment: issue has nothing to do with angular and all to do with how browser handles those events

Comment: Beside the main issue: `ng-focus="showSuggestions=true" ng-blur="showSuggestions=false"` is asking to be extracted to a directive. Also - are you trying to do something with the view? maybe target `input:focus {}` in CSS rather than use JS?

Comment: For a similar functionality , I created a directive which checks if the click is outside the whole typeahead thing, and dismiss the suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. However, you can use `ngMousedown` instead of `ngClick` to achieve the desired functionality:

**HTML:**

```
ng-mousedown="suggestionClicked($index, $event)
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.suggestionClicked = function(index, evt) {
    //detect left click
    if(evt.which === 1) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem while developing my own autocomplete dropdown list. Both $timeout and ng-mousedown solutions were too dirty for me and had negative UX side-effects. This is what I figured out eventually:

```
var suppressInputFocusedChange = false;

$scope.onBlur = function() {
    if(suppressInputFocusedChange === true) {
        suppressInputFocusedChange = false;
        return false;
    }
    $scope.showSuggestions = false;
};

$scope.onFocus = function() {
    $scope.showSuggestions = true;
};

$scope.suggestionMouseDown = function() {
    suppressInputFocusedChange = true;
};

$scope.suggestionClicked = function() {
    $scope.showSuggestions = false;
};
```

So basically, when you start to click on the item (ng-mousedown) you set the suppressInputFocusedChange flag to true. When this flag is up 'onBlur' method will do nothing and the list will be hidden by the suggestionClicked method.

Answer (score 0):

One of your options is use a `$timeout` to delay the removal of the suggestion list, and `$cancel` the timeout from the click event.

```
var suggestionTimeout = $timeout(angular.noop);

function setSuggestionFalse = function() {
    vm.showSuggestions = false;
 };

vm.onSmartBarBlur = function () {
    //delay the removal
    suggestionTimeout = $timeout(setSuggestionFalse, 50);
};

vm.onSuggestionClick = function () {
    //cancel the removal
    $timeout.cancel(suggestionTimeout);
    //show suggestion
};
```

For more information in $timeout see the [AngularJS $timeout API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).